# UIPopoverController does not appear

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I think I've spent 3 days trying various people's online solutions to make a popover appear and work and literally *not a single example* has worked.

But here is my current code. Can someone tell me why my popover is not appearing? Thanks.

```
popper = [[Popper alloc] initWithNibName: @"Popper" bundle: nil];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: popper];
[navigationController presentModalViewController: popper animated:YES];
[navigationController release];
[popper release];
```

Notes:

- My Popper class inherits from UIViewController.
- I have set my Xib's class to Popper in IB.
- I have set my main view controller to use UIPopoverControllerDelegate.

Comment: Not sure, but I usually create a property for the modals. This could be preventing it from acting properly. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

So have you added the navigationController to your view?

why not do:

```
[self presentModalViewController: popper animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that helps although for some reason my Xib's dimensions are being ignored and an entire 768x1024 window is sliding up on top of my main view.

Answer (score 0):

When you already initialise the navigation controller with a view all you need to do is add the navigation controller to your view.

```
[self.view addSubView: navigationController.view];
```

Dont present it as modal.

Answer (score 0):

For custom popovers, I recommend WEPopover

http://iosdevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-popover-api-for-iphone-wepopover.html

Just attach the view controller to the wepopovercontroller and you are done.

```
    WEPopoverController *popOver = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:saveViewController];

    [popOver presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    [saveViewControlle release];
```

Comment: if you use your custom pop over, as you mentioned, the model view controllers occupy whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

`UIPopoverController` is only available on the iPad, and since you've tagged your question with `iPhone` I'm assuming this may well be the issue.

Comment: I am coding for iPad actually. Oops.